# If statement not executed inside for loops

Tags: node.js

```
var total = [];
for(var i = 0; i < found.length; i++){
    if(total.length === 0){
            total.push(found[i]);
    }else{
        for(var x = 0; x < total.length; x++){
            if(total[x].price < found[i].price){//Here
                total.splice(x, 0, found[i]);
                console.log("Test");
                break;
            }else{
                 console.log("Testss");
                if(x === total.length - 1){
                    total.push(found[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working successfully
and test is consoled.log

```
for(var i = 0; i < found.length; i++){
    if(total.length === 0){
            total.push(found[i]);
    }else{
        for(var x = 0; x < total.length; x++){
            if(total[x].price > found[i].price){ //The sign changed here
                total.splice(x, 0, found[i]);
                console.log("Test");
                break;
            }else{
                 console.log("Testss");
                if(x === total.length - 1){
                    total.push(found[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is not working and i can't find a reason, it's only a sign
Note: The code is in other functions not in the same function
can anyone help?

The whole code:

```
  router.get("/shop", function(req, res){
        const range1    = parseInt(req.cookies.pricerange1);
        const range2    = parseInt(req.cookies.pricerange2);
        var category;
        var findattr = {};
        if(typeof req.query.search != 'undefined'){
            findattr = {name: req.query.search};
            req.cookies.category = -1;
        }
        if(typeof req.query.search === 'undefined'){
            category = -1;
        }else{
            category  = parseInt(req.cookies.category);
        }
        Product.find(findattr, function(err, found){
            if(err){
                req.flash("error", "An Error has occured, Please try again later.");
                res.redirect("/shop");
            }else{
                if(found.length === 0){
                    req.flash("error", "No Products were found, Try again later.");
                    return res.redirect("/");
                }
                var minvalue = 100000000000000000;
                var maxvalue = 0;
                var total = [];
                if(req.cookies.pricerange1 === undefined && req.cookies.pricerange2 === undefined){
                    for(var i = 0; i < found.length; i++){
                        if(found[i].price < minvalue){
                            if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){
                                minvalue = found[i].price;
                            }
                        }
                        if(found[i].price > maxvalue){
                            if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){
                                maxvalue = found[i].price;
                            }
                        }                    
                        if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){
                            if(req.cookies.sort === '0' || typeof req.cookies.sort === 'undefined'){
                                total.push(found[i]);
                            }
                            if(req.cookies.sort === '1'){
                                total.push(found[i]);
                            }
                            if(req.cookies.sort === '2'){
                                if(total.length === 0){
                                    total.push(found[i]);
                                }else{
                                    for(var x = 0; x < total.length; x++){
                                        if(total[x].price < found[i].price){//Here working
                                            total.splice(x, 0, found[i]);
                                            break;
                                        }else{
                                            if(x === total.length - 1){
                                                total.push(found[i]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(req.cookies.sort === '3'){
                                if(total.length === 0){
                                    total.push(found[i]);
                                }else{
                                    for(var x = 0; x < total.length; x++){
                                        if(total[x].price > found[i].price){//Here is the code not working
                                            total.splice(x, 0, found[i]);
                                            console.log("Test");
                                            break;
                                        }else{
                                            if(x === total.length - 1){
                                                total.push(found[i]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }else if(req.cookies.sort === '4'){
                                total.push(found[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        if(i === found.length - 1){
                            res.render("products/shop", {products: found, product: total, pageinfo:"Shop", 
                            minvalue: minvalue, maxvalue: maxvalue});
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(range1 != "NaN" && range2 != "NaN"){
                        var total = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < found.length; i++){
                            if(found[i].price < minvalue){    
                                if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){                        
                                    minvalue = found[i].price;
                                }
                            }
                            if(found[i].price > maxvalue){
                                if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){
                                    maxvalue = found[i].price;
                                }
                            }
                            if(found[i].price >= range1 && found[i].price <= range2){                            
                                if(category === found[i].category || category === -1){
                                    total.push(found[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            if(i === found.length - 1){
                                if(range1 < minvalue){
                                    if(range2 > maxvalue){
                                        res.clearCookie('pricerange1');
                                        res.clearCookie('pricerange2');
                                        res.render("products/shop", {error: "Please Choose the price ranges again", products: found, product : total, pageinfo: "Shop", minvalue: minvalue, maxvalue: maxvalue});
                                    }else{
                                        res.render("products/shop", {products: found, product : total, pageinfo: "Shop", minvalue: minvalue, maxvalue: maxvalue, minvaluechosen: range1, maxvaluechosen: range2, range: true});
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    res.render("products/shop", {products: found, product : total, pageinfo: "Shop", minvalue: minvalue, maxvalue: maxvalue, minvaluechosen: range1, maxvaluechosen: range2, range: true});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        res.clearCookie('pricerange1');
                        res.clearCookie('pricerange2');
                        req.flash("error", "Please Choose the price ranges again");
                        res.redirect("/shop");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

> Its for ecommerce app i am filtering the products from high price to
> low and from low to high so i did this code This is the whole code for
> whom want to see anyone have answer?? Note: When i make the if
> condition like the first example it works so the problem is from the
> statement it self

Comment: Which `if` do you expect to be executed? how do you know it's not executed? can you provide sample inputs `found` and `total`?

Comment: the if i put beside it a comment
found is the data came from mongo and it come as array
total is the data filtered from found
it's not executed because it didn't console.log in the second code

Comment: So this one? `if(total[x].price > found[i].price)`, Are you sure that's not because 
 of it enters this condition? `if(total.length === 0)`

Comment: it enteres the first time it loops but when it push to total so that condition is not true anymore

Comment: perhapse `found.length` is just `1`?

Comment: No found.length is 6 now

Comment: and it's not logging `console.log("Testss");` ?

Comment: yes it is consoling it till the two loops stop

Comment: Yes, your code just freezed my browser :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i read your comment

> yes it is consoling it infinetly

i'm sure the reason is

```
if(x === total.length - 1){
        total.push(found[i]);
  }
```

if x === total.length - 1, so you push a new data [found[i]] to [total], that makes change total length, then x++

this step will repeat everytime if you meet this case, it will loop infinitely and never run inside if statement, because found[i] is not change => your browser is stopped.

Comment: no if x === total.length -1 then  the second loop is over so the first one will loop again and if its for what are you saying why the else will be run if the if is working?

Comment: why did you think the second loop is over ? ex: total = 5, total.length - 1 = 4 and x = 4, then meet your if condition, u will add found[i] to total, then total.length = 6, x++ -> x= 5, so it will run else again because total[x].price == found[i].price and it will repeat this step infinity ?

Comment: i think you should add break; with if statement above , your problem will be resolved